# Getting 400 Bad Request on sending request using axios (ReactJS) even though it works fine on Postman

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I'm trying to GET a List of Patients from my BE using FormData with Bearer token. When I test on Postman, it resolves just fine, but when I try to send with axios, I constantly get the 400 Error Bad Request, can anyone know the problem ?? [this is where I send request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Lvw.png)
Here is my code for React

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useParams, Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { API } from '../../../api/GeneralAPI';
import FetchingError from '../../../Authentication/Views/ErrorView/FetchingError';
import SearchPatientUnderGuide from './SearchPatientUnderGuide';
function FetchPatientUnderGuide() {
    const {id} = useParams();
    console.log(id)
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const url = API + "getAllPatientsOfDoctor"
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const fetchPatients = async () => {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('id', id)
        console.log("ID is: " + formData.get('id'));
        console.log(`Bearer ${token}`)
        const fetchData = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            data : formData})
        return fetchData;
    }
    const query = useQuery('patients', fetchPatients)
    return ( 
        <div>
        {query.isLoading
        ? <ReactLoading type="spin" color="#0000FF"
        height={100} width={50}/>
        : query.isError
        ? <FetchingError />
        : query.data
        ? <div>
            <SearchPatientUnderGuide details = {query.data.data.object} />
        </div>
        : null}
        </div>
     );
}

export default FetchPatientUnderGuide
```

[This is the result I get when sending by React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b6Jk.png)

[I code my React code based on this on Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rApmy.png)

Comment: Try adding `...data.getHeaders()` to the headers, maybe that's the issue.

Comment: not sure but there're 2 common scenarios: 1) inspect logs in your server's endpoint to know if the request reached it and how it is processed. 2) sometimes your server returns status code above 300 and axios by default considers it as failure, if so just try changing the `validateStatus` properties of axios

Comment: No, it is not working. It raises new error TypeError: formData.getHeaders is not a function. 
P.s: I get this error when I add ...formData.getHeaders() as xaleel says. I even try adding ...data.getHeaders() but it is wrong as well

Comment: About irous answers: After I inspect the Back end's response (I use Spring boot), I get these information: 
+ When I send with Postman, the Back end can get the RequestParam id and resolves.
+ When I send with my React, the Back end has error because the request missing the required RequestParams. 
And I don't know what I do wrong here.

Comment: @kayenx00 ah I think you should use the `params: formData` for `get` request instead of `data: formData` (data is for `post` request)

Comment: tks for your answer irous, however that is not correct either :))
P/s: I find my answer. I change the URL to url = API + "getAllPatientsOfDoctor?id="+id; and it finally works. However, it raises another question, why formData does not append the id to the url ?? Now do I have to append manually everytime ??

Comment: @kayenx00 `FormData` is an object and used with XHR request. In axios, you can use `params` to pass url params such as `params: { id: id }`. using `params` will give you benefits: 1) you don't need to manually concatenate your query/param string. 2) axios will encode your params for you which is safer